# How to link featured images in single.php for only non-logged-in users?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I want to link featured images of every WordPress post automatically for only visitors. So it should not be available for logged-in users of WordPress. It should only link featured images of `single.php`. Not for `index.php`, `archive.php` or others.

I have this code but do not know where (which file in WordPress) this code should be placed:

```
<?php
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'large' );
        $link  = is_user_logged_in() ? $image : 'https://example.com/';
    ?>
```

Maybe we can put this in `functions.php` or `single.php`? But when I put this it breaks the site or doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This code that you are referencing needs to be placed somewhere within the loop in your `single.php` file. As this code is written, you will not see it make any sort of output to the screen since it is just saving `$image` and `$link` to variables.

You will need to do something like this to output the image:

```
<?php

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'large' );
$link  = is_user_logged_in() ? $image : 'https://example.com/';

?>

<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: I think that you would want to set $image to a tiny image (pixel) if user is not logged in. That will give a valid value for the img src in the href on the last line of your sample code in the answer. In fact, you might want to set the $link value to the featured image, or the pixel image, based on is_user_logged_in().